How to save and load spacy encodings in a Polars DataFrame
I want to use Spacy to generate embeddings of text stored in a polars DataFrame and store the results in the same DataFrame. Next, I want to save this DataFrame to the disk and be able to load again as a polars DataFrame. The backtransformation from pandas to polars results in an error.
This is the error message:
ArrowInvalid: Could not convert Hello with type spacy.tokens.doc.Doc: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type
Here is my code:
from io import StringIO
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
import spacy


nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")
json_str = '[{"foo":"Hello","bar":6},{"foo":"What a lovely day","bar":7},{"foo":"Nice to meet you","bar":8}]'


#Initalize and store DataFrame
df = pl.read_json(StringIO(json_str))
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("foo").map_elements(lambda x: nlp(x)).alias("encoding"))
df.to_pandas().to_pickle('pickled_df.pkl')

#Load DataFrame
df_loaded_pd = pd.read_pickle('pickled_df.pkl')
df_loaded_pl = pl.from_pandas(df_loaded_pd)


These are the package versions I used:
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pandas                    2.2.3           py312hf9745cd_1    conda-forge
polars                    1.9.0           py312hfe7c9be_0    conda-forge
spacy                     3.7.2           py312h6db74b5_0  
spacy-curated-transformers 0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
spacy-legacy              3.0.12             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
spacy-loggers             1.0.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge

Thank you for your help!

Is there a reason you're using pandas to save/load a Polars dataframe in the first place?

@orlp I think it's because they end up with an object dtype from the nlp() call. Polars doesn't seem to let you write an Object datatype to disk.

The error you are encountering is due to the fact that the spacy.tokens.doc.Doc object (the result of nlp(x)) is not compatible with Arrow, which Polars uses for its backend. Arrow cannot serialize complex Python objects like spacy's Doc directly.

Can you store nlp(x).to_bytes() instead which will give you a binary type? You can then use .write_parquet() to save to disk. nlp.from_bytes() could be used if you want to get the Doc objects back.

@orlp this was my workaround to store the spacy object as @jqurious already correctly mentioned. nlp(x).to_bytes() -> nlp.from_bytes() strangely results in a different object and calculating the similarity between the loaded docs and a newly created one results in the following error ComputeError: AttributeError: 'German' object has no attribute 'vector_norm'

Serializing and deserializing
SpaCy objects within a polars DataFrame can be stored by using SpaCys native DocBin class. The following code generates doc objects, saves them locally, and successfully loads them afterwards.
from io import StringIO
from spacy.tokens import DocBin
import polars as pl
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_md")
json_str = '[{"foo":"Hello","bar":6},{"foo":"What a lovely day","bar":7},{"foo":"Nice to meet you","bar":8}]'
doc = nlp("some text")

#Serialize polars DataFrame
df = pl.read_json(StringIO(json_str))
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("foo").map_elements(lambda x: DocBin(docs=[nlp(x)]).to_bytes()).alias('binary_embbeding'))
df.write_parquet('saved.pq')

#Deserialize polars DataFrame
df_loaded = pl.read_parquet('saved.pq')
df_loaded = df_loaded.with_columns(pl.col('binary_embbeding').map_elements(lambda x: list(DocBin().from_bytes(x).get_docs(nlp.vocab))[0]).alias("spacy_embedding"))

#Calculate similarity
df_loaded.with_columns(pl.col("spacy_embedding").map_elements(lambda x: doc.similarity(x), return_dtype=pl.Float64).alias('Score'))


Applying functions to deserialized SpaCy objects
Serializing and deserializing SpaCys objects with native polars functions (such as df.write_parquet()) heavily depends on the used model. In the above case the similarity calculation only works when utilizing SpaCys language model that contain wordvectors.
nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm") # Line 20 does not works
nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_md") # Line 20 works
nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_lg") # Line 20 works
nlp = spacy.load("de_dep_news_trf") # Line 20 does not works


